# undefined local variable or method `column' for main:Object when running csv import via rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am trying to learn Rails and one of the first exercises I wanted to lear was to automate csv import into database. So I created the model by using

```
rails g scaffold Domain  dns:string current_bid:integer join_by_pt:datetime bidders:integer seller:string tld:string length:integer words:string categories:string hyphnens:string numbers:string auction_type:string
```

Next I created the rake file:

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import domains from csv file"
  task :import => [:environment] do

  file = "db/dl.txt"

  CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
  entry = Domain.find_or_create_by(:dns => column[1])
  entry.bid = column[2]
  entry.join_date = DateTime.parse(column[3])
  entry.bidders = column[4]
  entry.seller = column[5]
  entry.tld = column[6]
  entry.length = column[7]
  entry.words = column[8]
  entry.categories = column[9]
  entry.hyphens = column[10]
  entry.numbers = column[11]
  entry.auction_type = column[12]
  entry.save 
 end

end
```

But when I try to run it, I get the error:

```
> rake aborted! undefined local variable or method `column' for
> main:Object /Users/user/drop/lib/tasks/import.rake:9:in `block (2
> levels) in <top (required)>'
> /Users/uer/drop/lib/tasks/import.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong and where my line of thinking went to the wrong direction please?

Thank you

Comment: You define "row" but not "column"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  make all of your `column` to `row`

```
desc "Import domains from csv file"
 task :import => [:environment] do

 file = "db/dl.txt"

 CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
  entry = Domain.new
  entry.dns =  row[1] unless row[1].nil?  
  entry.bid = row[2] unless row[2].nil?
  entry.join_date = DateTime.parse(row[3]) unless row[3].nil?
  entry.bidders = row[4] unless row[4].nil?
  entry.seller = row[5] unless row[5].nil?
  entry.tld = row[6] unless row[6].nil?
  entry.length = row[7] unless row[7].nil?
  entry.words = row[8] unless row[8].nil?
  entry.categories = row[9] unless row[9].nil?
  entry.hyphens = row[10] unless row[10].nil?
  entry.numbers = row[11] unless row[11].nil?
  entry.auction_type = row[12] unless row[12].nil?
  entry.save 
 end
end
```

Comment: That did it, well at least I got a different error so I now need to investigate that. Any pointers to why it is using row, when each of the items is defined as column in the database please? And the new error is: no implicit conversion of nil into String
/Users/tvetrovsky/drop/lib/tasks/import.rake:11:in `parse'
/Users/tvetrovsky/drop/lib/tasks/import.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: as in the loop you `CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|` point it to `row`..look at my updated post